# Converting TSV format to uploadble MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin, csv

I've a file dump which in TSV `.txt` format with around 1.9 million rows which is around 450 MB. What is the best way to upload such a huge database for a user who is using shared hosting with 50 MB limit on phpMyAdmin

Comment: `LOAD DATA INFILE` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: How do i specifically do this for TSV? And i presume I need to upload this file into root first?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? It defaults to using tabs as the field separator, so you don't have to do anything special for TSV. Yes, you need to upload the file to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I f you are using cpanel then go to your cpanel
for example :

https://cpanel.example.com:2083/frontend/x3/lveversion/option-selector.html

and change the /frontend/x3/lveversion/option-selector.html# to maximum available size.

Then go to https://www.phpmyadmin.net/ and upload the latest available version to your public_html folder. And then open your domain. for example domain.com/phpMyAdmin-4.5.1-all-language

login to server and then upload the 500mb database from the import option.